# React component simple render

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to react and following a tutorial https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/components-and-props.html

I have the code below. I don't understand why won't it render the contents.

```
function Welcome(props) {
  return <h1>Hello, {props.surname}</h1>;
}

function App(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <Welcome surname = {props.surname} />
      <Welcome surname = {props.surname} />
      <Welcome surname = {props.surname} />
    </div>
  );
}

function myApp(){
  return (
    <div>
      <App surname = "Simon" />
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <myApp/>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

I am following the similar example this one: https://codepen.io/gaearon/pen/KgQKPr?editors=0010

The only thing I did different was to add a different component on top and changed the props data.

Please let me know if I am missing on anything.

Answer (score 3):

The first letter of react component should be capital. So convert your `myApp` to `MyApp`

```
function MyApp(){
  return (
    <div>
      <App surname = "Simon" />
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <MyApp/>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```